# Finding $X_t$ of an Itô Diffusion

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Someone please help me with this:

I have that $X_t$ is the Ito diffusion with genertator $A(f)(x)=\alpha xf'(x)+f''(x).$

Then, if $X_0=x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, how do I find $X_t$?

Comment: Do you know Ito's formula? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the dynamics is given by
\begin{align*}
dX_t = \alpha X_t dt + \sqrt{2}\,dW_t.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
d\left(e^{-\alpha t} X_t\right) &=-\alpha e^{-\alpha t} X_tdt + e^{-\alpha t} dX_t\\
&=\sqrt{2}e^{-\alpha t} dW_t.
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
e^{-\alpha t} X_t = X_0 + \sqrt{2}\int_0^te^{-\alpha s} dW_s.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
X_t = e^{\alpha t} X_0 + \sqrt{2}\int_0^te^{-\alpha (s-t)} dW_s.\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> EDIT:

From $(1)$ and Ito isometry, 
\begin{align*}
E(X_t) &= E\left(e^{\alpha t} X_0 + \sqrt{2}\int_0^te^{-\alpha (s-t)} dW_s\right)\\
&=e^{\alpha t} X_0 + \sqrt{2}e^{\alpha t} E\left( \int_0^t e^{-\alpha s} dW_s\right)\\
&= e^{\alpha t} X_0,\\
Var(X_t) &= E\left(\left( \sqrt{2}\int_0^te^{-\alpha (s-t)} dW_s\right)^2 \right) \\
&=2\int_0^t e^{-2\alpha (s-t)} dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\alpha}\left(e^{2\alpha t}-1 \right).
\end{align*}

Comment: You can also integrate by parts to rewrite the solution in terms of a $ds$ integral.