# Solving an Ito Diffusion and finding the Expectation/Variance

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I have an example in which $Y_t$ is the Ito diffusion with generator $A(f )(x) = αxf '(x) + 2x^2f ''(x).$

Assume $Y_0 = y ∈ R^+.$

I would like to find $Y_t$ and from that would like to find $E [Y_t ]$ and $Var [Y_t ]$.

Can someone please walk me through this example?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890557/how-to-find-the-ex-t-and-varx-t-of-an-it%c3%b4-diffusion

Comment: that question does not seem to have a complete answer

Comment: The generator is different for [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890461/finding-x-t-of-an-it%C3%B4-diffusion/1890504?noredirect=1#comment3882783_1890504). Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

The dynamics is given by
\begin{align*}
dX_t = \alpha X_t dt + 2X_t dW_t.
\end{align*}
That is, $X_t$ is log-normal. The computation of the expectation and variance is then straightforward.